# C++: Find a certain folder regardless of if I am running the program from an IDE or as a standalone executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, filepath, relative-path

Let's say my program needs to access some file in folder 'Files', which is currently stored in bin. In Visual Studio, I can specify the current working directory to 'bin', so if I am running my code with Visual Studio then I can access folder Files by name only without any additional file path information. E.g.

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open("Files\\someFile.txt");
```

However, if I run my program as a standalone executable, then of course it won't be able to find Files. This is a problem because I intend to test it as a standalone executable.

What is the usual way to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your path in the registry. On your development system, you can add a key manually to the registry which contains the path, and when you release the software, you can use an installer to set this key to whatever you need. Look at [this link from the Microsoft web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/ms724871(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn how to use the registry.

If you know that your files are always located in the folder where your executable lives, you can also use [the windows API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) `GetModuleFileName` to retrieve the path to your executable. Sometimes this is useful in connection with a precompiler bloc like:

```
#ifdef STANDALONE
... GetModuleFileName ... 
#else
... [open hard coded path] ...
#endif
```

`STANDALONE` is a macro which you define when you want to test the software outside the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

When using relative path in your program you're basically asking OS to search it relatively to current working directory. Not from directory the executable is. So if you have your executable in the following location `C:\a\out.exe` and you are in `C:\b` calling it with `..\a\out.exe` you working directory would still be `C:\b`.
This what happens when you run from Visual Studio (by default).
You can change it in the project settings - Configuration Properties/Debugging. Change Working Directory from `$(ProjectDir)` to `$(TargetDir)`

---

UPD.

More info about MSVC project macros here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Comment: So what exactly is TargetDir?

Comment: @Jimmy_Rustle `$(TargetDir)` is set to the directory of your target. The target is an executable in your case. You can see more about current target settings in the Configuration Properties/General